# Достать код с закрытого Google Code

Tags: изображения, репозиторий

Очень нужно достать это: https://ehoeks-zopfli-png.googlecode.com/

Это единственный нормальный код для сжатия png с использованием zopfli, который я встречал. Ни тебе Node, ни странного выхода (.gz вместо .png, параметра для выхода в png просто нет), как у других.

Знаю, вопрос тупой(даже очень).
Там есть поиск, но он не работает как надо. Или я его неправильно использую.
Есть вариант достать код?

Comment: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/ehoeks-zopfli-png/source-archive.zip

Comment: а сверху там есть кнопка "export to github"